# Flask on RPI ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wanted my flask server to run when the RPI starts up. when it starts up, the script runs as normal, however when I go to visit the site, it gets a ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t error. This is weird because I don't get this error if I run it manually, only when the RPI starts it up on boot automatically.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC6pm.png)

Comment: This error usually comes up when `timestamp` is not configured correctly. So when it is interpreted as a datetime, it falls outside the range of possible dates. What exactly are you using to run the script on boot? `systemd`? You most likely have a mismatch in the environments between running manually and running on boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, the problem was actually that I hadn't cleared my browsing data on chrome. that was the issue.