# Updating browser cache on flask

Tags: python, flask, caching

I have a small flask server I'm running mostly for experimenting and tools I'm developing for self use (on my home network). It is running on development mode on a raspberry pi machine. It is configured to launch on startup via `rc.local`:

```
sudo -H -u pi /home/pi/Server/start.sh &
```

and the `start.sh` file reads

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi/Server
source /home/pi/Server/venv/bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=/home/pi/Server/app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_RUN_HOST=192.168.1.104
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=5001

flask run
```

At the first couples of days everything was running fine, but now I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2291, in wsgi_app
    ctx.push()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 377, in push
    self.app, self.request
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 343, in open_session
    data = s.loads(val, max_age=max_age)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 643, in loads
    .unsign(s, max_age, return_timestamp=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 466, in unsign
    return value, self.timestamp_to_datetime(timestamp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 404, in timestamp_to_datetime
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts + EPOCH)
OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

From what I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845184/flask-on-rpi-valueerror-timestamp-out-of-range-for-platform-time-t) This is an issue of browser cache. How can I tell flask to cope with this?

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Shift+R` on Windows (Not sure what it is for Mac)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. This doesn't work. Regardless. I hardly believe that this is the right solution. Generally speaking, webpages should load regardless if the user cache is updated or not.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using sessions/cookies? Try looking into that, maybe the date isn't proper or invalid. Try clearing it `session.clear()` or use a shorter expiration date. I've also had issues after upgrading from python 2 to 3 that messed up the cookies, if you've done that, you need to clear your cache so python3 date/time cookies can be set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Where should I place this?

Comment: you mean for the session.clear() ? usually at the start of the program before any sessions are set.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error when time returned is 0 from this [Adafruit CircuitPython NTP issue](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_NTP/issues/2). A direct approach would be to patch some flask dependencies with a PR.

However this seems more to be an error with your cache age. Try reducing it to a short time

```py
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=300" # in second
    return response
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I've tried updating the cache as per your suggestion (placed this in ``routes.py`` but it didn't work. Do you have any other suggestion? How should I patch the flask dependencies? I'm really in unfamiliar territory here, and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @Yotam then i think it's time for gunicorn or something similar. It is recommended beyond dev to use a real server ^^

Comment: Hi. I've tried using gunicorn for that yesterday. Still got the same error, but this might be an "echo" of the old configuration or just a false setup on my side. I'll read a bit more about gunicorn and see how I can set it up properly. Thanks.

Comment: Or even apache etc, like try a 'real' setup